# Registration/sign up in the context of an oAuth2 architecture

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

As we're still in the very beginning of the development of our oAuth2 architecture a discussion came up for where and how user registration should be handled. We basically have 3 components: [Identity Server 4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (STS), [ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) (Resource service), React.js (client) app. And the way it works now is that the client application gets tokens from the STS and then uses Bearer scheme to make calls to the resource API. All good. But the discussion point here is that our users are "hard-coded" on the STS. We know that Identity Server is not really for signing up users. So, for that purpose we decided to ask the community what would be the best option here in order to give our end users the ability to register.

In the current situation our users can login with pre-defined username/password or with their Google accounts as described [here](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html#adding-google-support).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a good questions and OAuth user onboarding is often not explained well. The design pattern used can vary, depending on the use case:

**SIGN UP USE CASES**

- User self sign up (without full proof of who the user is), eg in an online app where users purchase products.
- User self sign up (with proof of identity), eg in a government website, where new users perhaps scan a passport or provide a trusted eID to identify themselves.
- User provisioning by an administrator, eg in some types of corporate app, where it is common to also assign roles and permissions

**SELF SIGN UP**

When a user is allowed to self sign up, the Identity and Access Management (IAM) system needs to provide extensibility features that can be used at the time of initial authentication:

- A `Create Account` option on the login form, if applicable to that application
- The ability to capture fields of interest to your business domain, which might include a country code, eID or so on
- This can involve the use of one or more custom screens to capture fields (eg a medical number in a health related system)
- Some kind of verification of new users is usually needed, and one option is to capture an email then ask the user to verify it
- Then save the user supplied attributes, including custom ones, to the IAM database, and you may prefer to same some of these to your business data. The IAM system should provide an API (eg based on SCIM 2.0) to help with this.

I would recommend first designing how you would like this to work for your business solution, to clarify your requirements.

**ONBOARDING DESIGN**

In terms of designing how Identity Server should work for you, the recent Curity article on [Integrating with Business Data](https://curity.io/resources/learn/integrate-identity-business-data/) explains some common techniques and may give you some ideas for clarifying how your own solution should work.

**IDENTITY SERVER IMPLEMENTATION**

I think with Identity Server you will need to look into the [ASP.Net Identity](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html) extensibility features, and perhaps start with some spikes to perform actions in areas such as these:

- Add a Create Account button on the login screen
- Implement screens for custom User Registration to collect data
- Implement some type of User Verification, perhaps via email
- Use Identity Server and / or your own APIs to save the entered user data where you'd like it

Comment: I added a link to a detailed article on this topic and updated my answer. Some of this may not be relevant to your use case, but onboarding is one of the tricky areas of OAuth, so hopefully it helps you a little.